# Asymptotics for $p$-series with $p=1/2$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Reading solutions to a practice exam, and I come across this:
$$
O\left(\sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} {1 \over \sqrt{d}}\right)
 = O\left(x^{1/4}\right).
$$
There are $O(\sqrt{x})$ terms in the sum, which are bounded between $x^{-1/4}$ and $1$. It looks like using the number of terms and the *lower* bound would give this estimate, but I don't see how that's valid.

Comment: Hint: Approximate the sum from above and below by a suitable integral (the function will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparison to integrals,
$$
2\sqrt{n+1}-2=\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le\int_0^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{n}
$$
So
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}=O(\sqrt{n})
$$
plug in $n=\sqrt{d}$.

Comment: If I wanted to generalize this to other $p \in (0,1)$, the result is $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-p} = O(n^{1-p})$, right?

Comment: @Daniel: yes. The constant grows like $\frac1{1-p}$, so as $p\to1$, the constant gets very big.